# Best way to implement themes Using Angular 5 and SASS

Tags: angular, sass, themes

I shall implement themes in my Angular 5 application, it shall not be some default themes from a framework, but custom made themes. I did have a look on Angular Material, but there are a lot of default themes that I will not be using.

So I need an advice on the best way to implement custom themes using Angular 5 and SASS.

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to break your theme in terms of `high level containers/shell` components. These can be used to give layout to pages.

Then your theme can be broken down into `modules` and `providers` for widgets. So all your widgets can be imported.

With this, you can have some **ready to use lazy-loaded pages** like `login`, `register` etc

A sample tutorial to build a theme with angular and using `bootstrap 4` as css framework: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/create-angular-app-themes-with-bootstrap-4-sass-kendo-ui

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply :-)
Do you have a link to a tutorial or something else describing how this is implemented? Because i I am a little confused :-|

Comment: I have added link to answer. please accept or upvote the answer if it helped you